# Deploying Ribbon Button Across all sites in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, ribbon

I have created a custom ribbon button using SharePoint designer 2010 for a library in a site and have associated a workflow to it.
How to extend this functionality to all the sites in a site collection? 
If I create the custom ribbon button in the top most site of a site collection, can I have the functionality to be extended to all the sub-sites in that collection?
I am using SharePoint designer 2010 for the development, so is there a solution using SPD? I think using visual studio one can create a sandbox solution and apply that solution across all the sub-sites.
Are there any other tools to achieve this functionality?

Comment: After a bit more research I have understood that it is not possible to have a ribbon button across all the sub-sites using SPD. It is quite easy to implement using visual studio, where you have to add feature.xml and elements.xml and set the attributes of the XML accordingly.
Please correct me if I am wrong.
Thanks